# Live value availability checking using ajax in django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to implement a live check on availability of a value in a database using ajax in django forms.  I found many examples of ajax and PHP to check for availability of say a username or email, but could not find a pure python example. Is there a way I can pass an element's value to a python script which would then query a database for its availability?

Comment: receiving ajax is not any different at server than a form submit that doesn't redirect . What is the specific issue?

Comment: And the Ajax side is not going to be any different if the server is in Python, so why can't you just use the examples you have?

Comment: There is no specific issue per say, I was just trying to find out if I can use a python script instead of PHP, that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions.  I decided to give [jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)   plugin a try with remote option passing in the csrf token along with the ajax request and it worked! 
 I hope someone finds this useful. 
Note: Without passing the csrf token, I got a forbidden error!

```
var token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').prop('value');  
$('#inputform').validate({
    rules:{
       lots_name :{
          required:true,
          remote:{
              url: 'check_lots', //django view 
              type: 'post',
              data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':token},
          }, // remote ends here
        }, // lots_name ends here
     }, // rules end here
     messages:{
         remote: jQuery.validator.format('{0} exists, pick another!') //custom message
    },// messages end here
}) // validate ends here
```

Comment: Yes, if you use django you will either have to pass the token or turn off CSRF check for that view (not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the question is rather "what is ajax?". All it means is that it will do a POST or GET asynchronously with javascript instead of reloading the page. All you need to do is create a page in python that will return the value that you ask for and query that page. Here's an example using Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('username-availability/')
def username-availability():
    return jsonify(available=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Save this as service.py or something and run it. Then you can, with for instance jQuery ask this service to return the value (which we know will always be True):

```
$.get( "localhost:5000/username-availability/", function( data ) {
  alert( data );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an API endpoint with [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) then hit it with jQuery, like $.get(url).  Writing your own api endpoints by hand is the road to madness.